# Covariance between two sample means sampled successively without replacement.

Tags: statistics, sampling

Lets say i have a population of size N, where N > 1, with the values $y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4}, ... , y_{N}$. (Unknown Population Distribution)

Step 1: A Simple Random Sample without Replacement is taken out of size $n_{1}$ from a population of $N$. Let's call it Sample 1 $S_{1}$.

Step 2 : A Simple Random Sample without Replacement is taken out of size $n_{2}$ from a population of $N-n_{1}$. Let's call it Sample 2 $S_{2}$.

I have to show that covariance between the mean of these two samples is

$Cov(\bar y_{S1}, \bar y_{S2}) = \frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_{i}-\bar{y})^2}{N(N-1)}$

where $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}$

---

So far what i have is this :-

$Cov(\bar y_{S1}, \bar y_{S2}) = E(\bar y_{S1}\bar y_{S2}) - E(\bar y_{S1})E(\bar y_{S2})$

where $E(\bar y_{S1})=\bar{y}$ which makes
$Cov(\bar y_{S1}, \bar y_{S2}) = E(\bar y_{S1}\bar y_{S2}) - (\bar{y})
^2$

Am unable to proceed any further, not even sure if what i have so far is right.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You might note that $E[\bar y_{S2}\mid \bar y_{S1}] = \frac{1}{N-n_1}\left(N\bar y-n_1 \bar y_{S1}\right)=\bar y- \frac{n_1}{N-n_1}\left( \bar y_{S1}-\bar y\right)$ or something like that

Comment: @Henry, quite new to this.. am still lost i am afraid. Will try to factor in your point and try to solve. Thanks tho :)